# Show whatID name for Task in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

As per my requirement, i want to show whatID name in LWC for Task. I have gone through many link but didnt get appropriate solution.

Is there any way to implement is easily ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that using `lightning-input-field`/`lightning-output-field` for the `WhatId` would automatically present the name but I haven't tried it. (Or `apex:inputField`/`apex:outputField` in Visualforce.)

In Apex code a method like this when passed the `WhatId` would return the name:

```
String nameForId(Id id) {
    for (SObject sob : [Database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(''
            + ' select Name'
            + ' from ' + id.getSObjectType()
            + ' where Id = :id'
            + ' with security_enforced'
            )]) {
        return (String) sob.get('Name');
    }
    return null;
}
```

where the fact that an `Id` has a method that returns the SObject type is used plus dynamic SOQL.

These are security related:

- `String.escapeSingleQuotes`
- `with security_enforced`